# How to properly export an ES6 module function as a library for use in a node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, es6-modules

Let's say that I have a node.js application, which does NOT go through my webpack bundling:

**Node App**

> ```
> const  Html = require('./build/ssr-bundle.js');
> let result = Html.ssrbundle.render();
> console.log(result);
> ```

Here is my ES6/JSX file, which is getting processed by webpack and I want to be able to access that render function in my node app (you guessed right, I am trying to SSR react stuff ;) )

**src/Html.js -(webpack)-> build/ssr-bundle.js**

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import  ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
> import  CustomComponent from './custom-component.js';
>
>
> module.exports = {
>      render : function () {
>          return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomComponent />);
>      } };
> ```

And here is my Webpack config

**webpack.config.js**

> ```
>  var path = require('path');
>  module.exports = {
>      entry: {
>          ssr: './src/Html.js',
>          //frontend: './src/frontend-Html.js'
>      },
>      output: {
>          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
>          filename: 'ssr-bundle.js',
>              library: 'ssrbundle'
>      },
>      module: {
>          rules: [
>              {
>                  test: /\.js$/,
>                  loader: 'babel-loader',
>                  query: {
>                      presets: ['env','react'],
>                      plugins: ["transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
>                  }
>              },
>              {
>                  test:/\.css$/,
>                  use:['style-loader','css-loader']
>              }
>          ]
>      },
>      stats: {
>          colors: true
>      },
>      devtool: 'source-map'
>  };
> ```

Whatever I do, I cannot figure out how to properly use that exported variable "ssrbundle" and subsequently the render function. If I had my node app included in the bundle, everything would be all right, but this is not what I want to do.

Comment: I think you need to use [`libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget) in your webpack config to define how you're going to expose the bundle

Comment: a specific option of libraryTarget did the trick. Thanks. I will post the solution below in detail

Answer (score 1):

As apokryfos suggested, I played around with the libraryTarget Webpack setting. You can find more info on using Webpack to author a library (what I was really trying to achieve) here:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

and here are code examples:

https://github.com/kalcifer/webpack-library-example/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js.

What did the trick for me, was to set the libraryTarget to "umd" , which is different than the "var" setting which is set by default and is suitable i.e. for including the script in an HTML file